# CSS fails to load after refreshing a page. After the second refresh it works again and so on

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a web site on Rails. And I've got the following problem: first a page is loaded with CSS, but when I refresh the page CSS fails to load. After the second refresh it works fine again and so on.

On localhost there is no such a problem, but in production there is.
This is my first Rails project and I don't even know, how to google this problem :)

Comment: Can you paste the error you're getting?

Comment: There is no error. According to log everything is fine both times when the page is loaded with CSS and when it is loaded without CSS with bare html.

Comment: Are you using something like webrick with your rails app?

Comment: @Michael Check your javascript console. You might get some errors.

Comment: I use Unicorn with my rails app.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. I've found errors in js console. Thanks!

Comment: More details are needed before this question can be answered correctly.