# css mistake after the second page load

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, minify

I am having a problem on a wordpress website, when loading the site for the first time all over load properly, if I try to reload the page you can see a problem (seems to be a css problem), this only happens if you use the button reload of  the browser, if I click on the logo link  or send with keyboard this does not happen

This problem occurs only when it is activated the plugin https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/

when i see the problem , in chrome console i see some error example :

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ppp/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/lib/HTTP/ConditionalGet.php:360)
```

this is the website where i found the problem http://shoutkey.com/jicama

similar problem is also mentionated on this discussion [CSS fails to load after refreshing a page. After the second refresh it works again and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892398/css-fails-to-load-after-refreshing-a-page-after-the-second-refresh-it-works-aga)

Comment: Looks like something is trying to modify the header after it was already sent (like trying to do a header redirect after doing an `echo`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163261/errror-warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by

Comment: @Manthan Dave thanks for your link, but never option have helped me, this is a very abnormal problem , if click on logo link  or click send of my keyboard work fine, not work only when click the reload button of browser !

Comment: @Carcigenicate, you can  check the source code  of plugin on this link https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/bwp-minify/tags/1.3.3/  ?